# Right way to adapt the size of a DataTemplate to the current resolution

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

Let's say I have a simple ListBox like this:

```
<!--Data template for the color samples-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <ContentControl>
        <Border BorderThickness="4"
                Margin="4,4,4,0"
                Height="{Binding BorderSize}"
                Width="{Binding BorderSize}">
            <Grid>
                <Polygon Points"{Binding BorderSize, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverterThatDoesStuff}}"/>
                <Canvas Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                <Image Source={Binding Image}/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>

<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Now, suppose I have a certain number of elements inside my Source (of course it may vary) and I want to display them with a fixed number of elements per row.

As you can see, I actually used this workaround: inside my DataModel I have something like this:

```
public class DataTemplateViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static double BorderSize
    {
        get { return (Window.Current.Bounds.Width - 80) / 4; }
    }

    private ImageSource _Image;

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return this._Image; }
        set
        {
            if (this._Image != value)
            {
                this._Image = value;
                OnNotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    // Let's say here I have the interface implementation...
}
```

As you can see, my BorderSize parameter returns the width of my screen minus a fixed constant (the margin of various UI elements outside the ListView), divided by 4.
Now, with this trick I get my images displayed 4 by 4 on each line, and that's what I want.

My point though is that I as far as I know, my DataModel shouldn't be connected to my View level at all, and here instead I have it calculate the effective pixel width of its DataTemplate.

It works fine, but I guess there's a better way to do it.

How can I set some properties of a DataTemplate (the Height and Width of that Border in this case) at runtime?

Thanks!
Sergio

Comment: using `WrapGrid.MaximumRowsOrColumns` not an option?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware It works, and I placed my ListBox inside a ViewBox and now it gets resized to fit the whole screen in width, and that's what I wanted. There's a problem though: how can I implement now that Converter I have for the Polygon inside the DataTemplate (I updated my question, you can see that there).
I tried naming the Border and binging the Polygon to its ActualHeight, but it's 0 and all the UI gets messed up. How can I do that without binding it to my Property inside the DataModel? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could define a property for your BorderSize in your ViewModel

```
private double borderSize=(Window.Current.Bounds.Width - 80) / 4;

public double BorderSize
{
    get { return borderSize; }
    set { borderSize = value; }
}
```

and simply bind this property to the height and width of your grid or border in DataTemplate

```
<Border Height={Binding BorderSize} Width={Binding BorderSize}/>
```

Comment: I thought about that, but the DataContext of each DataTemplate that gets generated is the DataModel of its relative item, and not my page ViewModel, so I can't bind to a ViewModel Property from there :/